# In Word, can you turn off auto-capitalization of first letter of sentence just for a particular doc?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Microsoft Word, can Auto-capitalisation be turned off, just for one particular document? I like autocapping but I don't want it in this particular document.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible for one document, it's all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

### The answer is "no."

This is an AutoCorrect option and is for your computer, not for a particular document.

It is not part of spelling correction, so you cannot mark text to not have it apply.

Answer (score 0):

As Charles Kenyon said, Word can only set autocorrect options, it can't enable initial capitalization for a specific document. If you want to change the capitalization, you can uncheck **sentence capitalization** and **table cell capitalization** in Settings-Proofing-AutoCorrect Options.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gud7Q.png)